# com.google.zxing.NotFoundException Decode Issue for QR Code Process in Spring Boot with JUnit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, qr-code, zxing

I have a problem to run any test method of QrServiceTest. I got the issue shown below

```
com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
```

The problem line is at this part (`new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitMap)`).

I cannot decode the bitmap. How can I fix it?

Here is the dependency which I used for qr

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the QrServiceTest shown below

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class QrServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    QrService qrService;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void createQrCodeWithoutImage() {
        var requestDTO = DummyData.getDummyCreateQrRequestDTO();

        var responseDTO = qrService.createQrCode(requestDTO);

        assertThat(responseDTO).isNotNull();
        assertThat(responseDTO.getBody()).isNotNull().isNotEmpty();


        var binaryBitMap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseDTO.getBody())))));

        var result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitMap);

        assertEquals(result.getText(), requestDTO.getText());
        assertEquals(result.getBarcodeFormat(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void createQrCodeWithImage() {
        var requestDTO = DummyData.getDummyCreateQrRequestDTO();
        requestDTO.setImage(new ClassPathResource("java-original-wordmark.png").getInputStream().readAllBytes());

        var responseDTO = qrService.createQrCode(requestDTO);

        assertThat(responseDTO).isNotNull();
        assertThat(responseDTO.getBody()).isNotNull().isNotEmpty();


        var binaryBitMap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseDTO.getBody())))));

        var result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitMap);

        assertEquals(result.getText(), requestDTO.getText());
        assertEquals(result.getBarcodeFormat(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

    }
}
```

The problem is here

```
var binaryBitMap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
                new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseDTO.getBody())))));

        var result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitMap);
```

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/qr-generator-example)

Comment: I have the same problem. I have tried scaling down and up the image in question, tried a range of images that my phone seems to have no problems reading